# Windows 10 desktop turning itself on at random times

Tags: windows-10, operating-systems, power, desktop-computer

First post so let me know if you guys need more info.

I have a gaming computer I built ~3 years ago, upgraded from 7 to 10 when it was free, and I shut it down whenever I'm not using it. For the last six months or so it's powered itself on at random times of the day (and night), with no clear indication in Event Viewer as to why. I have a local backup configured to run once a week on Sunday afternoon, and virus scans say the computer is clean. It's gotten to the point where I can look over at it at any point in the day and it will be on.

Because of the way I need it set up, I recently (more recently than this problem has been occurring) set my computer up to stay awake for 3 hours after inactivity, so having it turn itself on and stay on for no reason is messing with my power bill. Any suggestions as to what may be causing it? Some weird Windows update policy or such?

I'll be back at my computer later today and can look for specific Event Viewer events then. Any suggestions or recommendations are appreciated.

Comment: I've had this happen to me with various versions of Win 10 going back to beta.  Never found a solution that works.

Comment: Please check your BIOS and network configuration for Wake On LAN and MagicPacket configurations. Also, is the computer shutting down, or is it sleeping/hibernating?

Answer (score 0):

Find Event ID 6005 and 6005 to log exact system start/stop time, confirm that if there is specific time interval of automatic system start.

Besides, access hardware provider’s official website, search for appropriate deriver (based on hardware model)which is applied to Windows 10, update or re-install hardware driver to check the result. including BIOS, Firmware and etc.